# How to identify the user's account type?

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to query Box API to identify if a user has a free or a paid account. So far I was able to query:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?fields=enterprise
```

and I checked that if a user have a free account the attribute "enterprise" is null. But the problem is I can't distinguish between a paid account and a developer account because the have the same info on enterprise object:

```
{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "123",
    "enterprise": {
        "type": "enterprise",
        "id": "456",
        "name": "..."
    }
}
```

Is there a way to identify theses 3 types of account (free, paid and developer)?

Comment: A developer account is functionally equivalent to an enterprise account (at least from an API perspective). Is there any particular reason why you need to make this distinction?

Comment: Yes, because in my app I need to use the static URL from the files and a developer account doesn't allow me to use this feature, making dev accounts not suitable for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can only check whether or not the user has an enterprise by calling the GET /users/me endpoint.

```
{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "123",
    "enterprise": {
        "type": "enterprise",
        "id": "456",
        "name": "..."
    }
}
```

and checking to see if the `enterprise` attribute is null to distinguish between a personal and enterprise user.

Comment: Ok, accepting the answer.. But I sent an email to support asking if `type` attribute could be changed to send values as "enterprise" and "developer" then I'll be able to distinguish between them.